# FoxPro Deleting after specific

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am trying to replace text after "/" on foxpro. Shelly Jones/Foundation Director, How to delete everything after the "/"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way of doing it is to combine the `left()` and `atc()` functions, like so:

```
lcStr = "Shelly Jones/Foundation Director"
lcNewStr = LEFT(lcStr, ATC('/', lcStr) - 1)
```

The `-1` is needed to get the portion of the string ending before the / character.

Comment: how would I go about deleting everything before the /. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is VFP 7 or later, use the StrExtract function:

```
cResult = STREXTRACT(cOriginalString, '', '/')
```

Comment: This worked well. Now, how would I go about deleting everything before the /. thanks in advance

Comment: Same function: 

cResult = STREXTRACT(cOriginalString, '/')